# vlc http interface file path encoding

Tags: javascript, encoding, vlc

I almost have this problem fixed but I'm building a remote on top of the VLC http interface and am having trouble encoding the `&` symbol.

For example I get a file name that looks like

```
C:\Users\Me\Music\Library\I Need a Doctor feat(Eminem & Skylar Grey)
```

But what VLC gets when I escape + url encode the file name is

```
C:\Users\Me\Music\Library\I Need a Doctor feat(Eminem
```

What do I do to fix this?

My pseudo-JavaScript:

```
function escapePath(string){
    var fixed = "";
for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    if(string[i] == "\\"){
        fixed += "\\\\";
    }
    else if(string[i] == "&"){
        fixed += "%26"; // Doesn't work with or without this
    }
    else{
        fixed += string[i];
    }
}
    return encodeURIComponent(fixed);
}
```

I know it's bad but I cant get `.replace()` to work correctly. Curse my horrible knowledge of regex. I'll fix that later

Comment: Try this: http://phpjs.org/functions/rawurlencode:501

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marc B. It worked with some tweaks.

The final function ended up looking like:

```
return encodeURIComponent(str.replace(/!/g, '%21').replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/\*/g, '%2A').replace(/\\/g, "\\\\"));
```

I only wish I knew why this works.